# Geração de Objetos em Json + Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

To começando agora em Python + Json e queria saber como posso fazer para gerar um OBJETO dentro do JSON.

Vejam só eu tenho um dataframe que tem as colunas

Name fancyName birthday rg document documentType email cep street number neighborhood city state phone1 phone2 gender creditLimit

[DataFrame Cliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vr3G.png)

Porém eu preciso que no meu JSON os dados do endereço sejam salvos em um objeto, para eu ler ele futuramente, ou seja, o JSON que preciso gerar é da seguinte forma: { "name": "CONSUMIDOR", "documentType": "2", "rg": null, "document": 24151, "birthday": "", "phone1": "", "phone2": "", "email": "teste@teste.com.br", "fancyName": "", "creditLimit": "0.0000", "address": [{ "street": "", "neighborhood": "NAO INFORMADO", "city": null, "state": "RS", "cep": null, "number": "0" }] }

Ou seja, adicionar um objeto ADDRESS que contenham tudo os dados do endereço.

Já tentei de diversas formas e sem sucesso, alguma sugestão

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o método to_json() para converter a dataframe em json. Depois inseres uma chave para a morada com o objeto que queres e removes as chaves que foram adicionadas. Por fim escreves o ficheiro json.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
 
data = {'name':['CONSUMIDOR'], 'fancyName':[''], 'birthday': [''], 'rg': [None], 'document': [24151], 'documentType': [2], 'email': ['consumidor@email.com'], 'cep': [None], 'street': [''], 'number': [''], 'neighbourhood': [''], 'city': [''], 'state': ['RS'], 'cep': [None], 'phone1': [''], 'phone2': [''], 'creditLimit': [0.0000]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
print(df)

json_file = df.to_json(orient='records')

json_obj = json.loads(json_file)
result = []

for i in json_obj:
    i['address'] = [{'street': i['street'], 'number': i['number'], 'neighbourhood': i['neighbourhood'], 'city': i['city'], 'state': i['state'], 'cep': i['cep']}]
    i.pop('street')
    i.pop('number')
    i.pop('neighbourhood')
    i.pop('city')
    i.pop('state')
    i.pop('cep')
    result.append(i)

json_final = json.dumps(result)
    
with open('my_data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_final)
```